# Вопрос по навигации по директориям xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Впервые сел за c# xamarin т.к. возникла острая нужда..

Как обратиться к определенной папке другого приложения/просто папке ? Пытаюсь отталкиваться от этого:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Получаю `/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/files`

Хотелось бы получить `/data/user/0` (я так понимаю это корень). А от него уже через `Path.Combine` (если это правильно) выстраивать путь

Думал получится делать шаги назад по типу `../../` и т.п.., но нет. Нагуглить не смог, либо неправильно гуглю. Как правильно сделать задуманное ?

Comment: Создайте экземпляр Directory и используйте Parent например

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! А через  Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path); + path.combine является допустимым ? Еще хотел бы узнать..во время дебага ругается: `Access to the path '/data/user/0' is denied.'`. Как это поправить можно?

Comment: В андройде нельзя залезать в любое место файловой системы и делать там что вздумается, иначе пенвое попавшееся приложение могло бы сломать вам телефон. 1) нужны разрешения приложению на достп к файлам 2) нужны привелегии пользователю. Например если пользователь root, и у приложения есть все разрешения, то вся файловая система будет доступна для записи. Но обычно это не нужно.